# Windbg - possible to suppress output for .outmask 1 or .outmask /d?

Tags: scripting, windbg

I am using a `.do` loop in a Windbg script and all the logic is working fine.

Within that `.do` loop I am doing a `.f+` and I've used `.outmask- 1` to suppress the chattiness of `.f+`, where it echoes back the frame to you, like so `23 00000002a9a2f7b0 0000000000000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d`. It can now iterate around the frames of a stack without echoing each frame back to the Command Window.

However, upon *resetting* `.outmask` with *either* `.outmask 1` or `.outmask /d` the following line is always echoed `Client 00000000002873A0 mask is 3F7` to the Command Window.

As I'm in a loop where my objective is to suppress the verbose output from the `.f+`, the last thing I want is for `.outmask` to be just as chatty *within* that loop. Is there a way of suppressing that too?

My loop looks like this:

```
  .frame 0n0
  r $t0 = 0

  .do
  {
    !for_each_local .if ($spat ("@#Local","foo") == 1) { ?? foo->bar }

    .outmask- 1
    .f+
    .outmask 1
    r $t0 = @$t0+1
  }
  (@$t0 < @$t1)
}
```

Comment: WinDbg scripting with builtin commands is quite messy. Did you have a look in alternative solutions such as the JavaScript interface, [tag:pykd] or [tag:mdbg]?

Comment: Thanks. That's a fair comment; and _has_ been mentioned - but I'm _trying_ to solve a real-world problem and I am limiting myself to Windbg scripting (for the time-being). There have been other challenges, where it seems Javascript would have been easier, but others have helped me surmount those... the introduction of `.outmask` was an example. For the time-being, at least, I want to stick with just Windbg scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinDbg's internal scripting capabilities are somewhat messy. IMHO WinDbg is not really designed for such tasks. If you need more complex scripts, try [pykd](/questions/tagged/pykd), [mdbg](/questions/tagged/mdbg) or [JavaScript Debugger Scripts (Microsoft)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/javascript-debugger-example-scripts)

A general way to prevent output of something is

```
.foreach (output {<put your command here>}) {}
```

i.e. in your case

```
.foreach (output {.outmask 1}) {}
```

It passes each word of the output as the variable `output` to the loop and the loop does nothing with it.

I hope that you're able to integrate this into your script without any other side effects.

The following script works for me when running with `$>a<`:

```
.echo "Before"
.frame 0n0
r $t0 = 0
.do { 
    !for_each_local .if ($spat ("@#Local","foo") == 1) { ?? foo->bar } 
    .outmask- 1
    .f+
    .foreach (output {.outmask 1}) {}
    r $t0 = @$t0+1 
}
(@$t0 < @$t1)
.echo "After"
```

Comment: I would _never_ have figured that out! Just in case you were wondering - it works... it works really well.

Comment: Very helpful - thank you. *And* it can (obviously to you, I guess) be _just_ `.outmask- 1`, then `.f+` then `.foreach (output { .outmask 1 }) {}`.

Comment: And, of course, I've _just_ realised I can forgo `.outmask` completely if I just use the `.foreach` method of suppression for `.f+`, that being `.foreach (output { .f+ }) {}`. The end result is exactly the same!